# C# + LINQ - inner join

Tags: sql, linq, select, join

```
Table: one
Column (PK): employee_ssn
Column: employee_active bit

Table: two
Column (pk): date
Column (FK): employee_ssn
Column: total_income
Column: total_expenses
```

Working Linq code to sum total_income and total_expenses for the year, per employee:

```
var SumOfSections = db.two
                .Select(x => x)
                .Where(x => x.employee_ssn.Equals(xxxxxxxxx))
                .Where(x => x.Date.Year.Equals(year))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Total_Income = g.Sum(x => x.total_expenses),
                    Total_Expenses= g.Sum(x => x.total_income)
                })
                .ToArray();
```

I need to incorporate INNER JOIN to the above to only include active employees.  Working SQL:

```
select two.total_income,total_expenses
from two
    INNER JOIN one  
        ON one.SSN = two.SSN
        WHERE one.Active = 1 AND two.Date='1/1/2014' AND two.SSN='xxxxxxxxx';
```

How can I modify my linq code to what my sql code is doing?

Comment: Just a doubt  : why is total_income a sum of total_expenses, and vice versa ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var SumOfSections = (from t in db.two
                     join o in db.one on t.employee_ssn equald o.employee_ssn
                     where t.employee_ssn = "xxxxxxxxx" && o.employee_active == true
                     group t by t.date into g
                     select new {
                         Total_Income = g.Sum(x => x.total_expenses),
                         Total_Expenses= g.Sum(x => x.total_income)
                     }).ToArray();
```

I used query syntax because it seems to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also continue with the notation you are using:

```
var SumOfSections = db.two.Join(db.one, o=>o.employee_ssn, t=>t.employee_ssn, (o,t)=>new {One = o, Two = t)
                .Select(x => x)
                .Where(x => x.Two.employee_ssn.Equals(""))
                .Where(x => x.Two.date.Year.Equals(1234))
                .Where(x=> x.One.employee_active == true)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Two.date)
                .Select(g => new
                {

                    Total_Income = g.Sum(x => x.Two.total_expenses),
                    Total_Expenses = g.Sum(x => x.Two.total_income)
                })

                .ToArray();
```